# Can't upload a file to Laravel with jQuery .post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

here's my html

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="file-name" id="file-id">
```

here's JS that is supposed to send file to api

```
var file = $('input#file-id').val();
$.post('my/url/that/works', {
    file: file,
    volume: volume
}).done(function () {
    //something
}).fail(function () {
    //something else
});
```

and finally my method in Laravel:

```
public function ajaxMethod(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        echo "it does";
    }else{
        echo "it does not"; //     <- that happens
    }
    var_dump($request->getContent());//vardumps ('C:/fakepath/[correct_filename])
}
```

and the ajax call says that it does not has a file. I think that I upload only file name, but not the file. How can I change it?

Comment: Indeed, you cannot upload a file using the jQuery post function.

Comment: ok, so I would need to use .ajax function?

Comment: When sending files in a request you need to encode them as binary data, not serialise them. To do that use a `FormData` object. See the duplicate I marked for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get file usei this:

```
var file = $('input#file-id').prop('files')[0];
```

instead of your code: `var file = $('input#file-id').val();`

Comment: This is half an answer. The bigger issue is the lack of binary data.

Comment: yes, I saw your comment about $.post

Comment: $request->file('image')->store('images');